# Custom ToolStripButton for ToolStrip in Visual Studio Designer form

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio-2008, designer, toolstrip

I have custom tool strip button

```
BindableToolStripButton : ToolStripButton
```

It works well, but I don't know possibility to add this item to control in design menu..

[image]

Could I add my BindableToolStripButton to the designer menu?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this attribute before your custom BindableToolStripButton class definition

[ToolStripItemDesignerAvailability(ToolStripItemDesignerAvailability.All)]

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. when I changed the declaration from

```
class MyToolStripButton : ToolStripButton
```

to

```
public class MyToolStripButton : ToolStripButton
```

it worked on the designer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to derive from [ToolStripControlHost Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripcontrolhost.aspx) like shown [ESharp-online](http://en.csharp-online.net/Tool,_Menu,_and_Status_Strips%E2%80%94Hosting_Other_Controls_in_the_ToolStrip).